# LT Codes encoding with replacement

Tags: coding-theory

I have read a Luby’s paper and understand basic idea of the LT codes, but I want to figure out the analysis when encoding symbols can choose their neighbors with replacement during the encoding process. I have tried some key points like, Repetitive, with replacement... on IEEE.I can not find related paper.
Do you have any relevant paper or documents ?

Comment: Welcome! Please ask a specific question. What do you not understand exactly? We answer questions, we don't answer reference requests. Please provide context. What is Luby's paper, and how did you encounter the problem? Thank you!